# problems with select option text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the text value of the select option here and i keep getting the value what am i doing wrong
 here is the code

```
 jQuery.each(jQuery('select.personalize_toggle'),function(i){
    var t = jQuery(this).html();
    alert(t);
 });
```

here is the html

```
 <select class=" personalize_toggle " >
    <option value="0" ></option>
    <option value="1" >Vargas</option>
 </select>
```

I want to get 'Vergas' out the select in my jquery each loop

**Another try**

```
  jQuery.each(jQuery('select.personalize_toggle option:selected'),function(i){
    var val = jQuery(this).text();
    alert(val); // also alerts 1
 });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get it like this:

```
alert($('#selectbox_id option:selected').text());
```

Where `selectbox_id` is the `id` of the `<select>` element. If you want to get the `value` of option, use `val()` instead of `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('select.personalize_toggle')
```

returns each select element from your question you seem to want the html inside the option tags i.e. "Vargas" in this case you should change your selector to

```
jQuery('select.personalize_toggle option')
```

This will return each option value and alert the contents.

Comment: close I don't want all the option values just the selected one

Comment: Ah sorry you didn't realised use the one you selected as an answer with the text() method.

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery code you have `select.personalize_toggle` but you have spelled it differently in html: `class=" personalize_toogle "`. So correct the spelling, and use `.text()` to get the text of the option (as pointed by Sarfraz).